# How to execute a function on the main app from a background task

Tags: c#, uwp, background-task

I am currently developing an HMI that must connect to a remote server on the same network to be able to start. To do this, I use the splash screen feature of the UWP platform that allows me to simulate a loading page.

My problem is that I have to receive the word  "start" by the server to be able to unlock my splash screen and pass on the application.

So I tried to call this function directly from my background but inevitably it does not work.

The functions to exit the splash screen:

```
void DismissedEventHandler(SplashScreen sender, object e)
{
    dismissed = true;
}

public void DismissExtendedSplash()
{
    rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
    Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
}

void DismissSplashButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DismissExtendedSplash();
}
```

SocketActivtyTask:

```
case SocketActivityTriggerReason.SocketActivity:
   var socket = socketInformation.StreamSocket;
   DataReader reader = new DataReader(socket.InputStream);
   reader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
   await reader.LoadAsync(250);
   var dataString = reader.ReadString(reader.UnconsumedBufferLength);

   try
   {
      if (dataString.Equals("Start"))
      {
          Debug.WriteLine("Lancement OK.");
          DismissExtendedSplash();
      }
    }
    catch
    {
          Debug.WriteLine("Lancement FAIL.");
    }
   }
```

How can I make it work ?

An additional question, how to cancel the background task when closing the application?

Comment: How did you configure your background task? Did you configure it to run in a separate process? (Probably, since that's what most people do.) If you do that, then when you call `DismissExtendedSplash`, you're not calling the foreground process. But why use a background task at all? Let the foreground task listen on the socket.

Comment: I use a background task because after in my main program I need to receive informations from the server. I need to receive message and after make a sort of switch to execute different task in my main program.

Comment: My suggestion was to have the foreground process take over the socket from the socket broker when it starts up. Then it's all in one process again. (Alternatively, you can configure your background task to run in the same process as the foreground app.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in your case, you should use what we call **BackgroundTask** as your best practice. To do this, you need first implement **IBackgroundTask** in your application, which will allow you to trigger a specific event .

MSDN Link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-a-background-task

Comment: Yeah, I already have a Background Task in my application. I'll have a closer look at the trigger function.

Answer (score 3):

Never do any tasks that take time from the application thread.  That is a sure way to introduce performance problems (at best) or deadlocks (at worst) into your application.  Use a `BackgroundWorker` for tasks that will take time.  Use the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler to update your application's UI when the task is done.

Here is a relatively simple example of implementing the `BackgroundWorker` class:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99143/BackgroundWorker-Class-Sample-for-Beginners

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response but I don't think it works on UWP Plateform, it's a Windows Form exemple. My application is not blocked waiting for the answer, later in the main menu I also expect simple messages. It is not possible to just return the value received or to make a switch to perform different functions?